# Generic Lookup Method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm wanting to create a generic lookup method to where you specify a type of object and some other identifying parameters and the method returns an object of that type. Is this possible?

I'm thinking something like this.

```
public T GetObjectOfType(Guid ID, typeof(T Class))
{
     //lookup this object and return it as type safe
}
```

I know this just won't work but i hope it explains the concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic method for this:

```
public T GetObjectOfType<T>(Guid id) where T: class, new()
{
    if (id == FooGuid) //some known identifier
    {
        T t= new T(); //create new or look up existing object here
        //set some other properties based on id?
        return t;
    }
    return null;
}
```

If all you want is create an instance of a specific type you do not need the additional id parameter, I assume you want to set some properties etc. based on the id. Also your class must provide a default constructor, hence the `new()` constraint.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would be used.  Since you have to pass in the type at compile time, why wouldn't you just call new yourself instead of delegating it to this method?  I could understand a factory method that returns a type that implements some interface based on a parameter, but T could be any reference type with a default constructor, so what's the point?

Comment: @Ed S.: without clarification I'm not so sure myself (as presented I admit its pretty useless) - could be a caching layer, i.e. look up a cached object instead of creating a new one, but of course this is just a guess.

Comment: This is the basics of a Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control framework; you request instances of an interface and the concrete returned is defined by either default convention using assembly scanning or some sort of type registry.  see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx

Comment: alternatively you could use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T);`

Comment: @RPM1984: That's why I started with - but it's not needed if there's a default constructor

Comment: Its for a testing framework, I want the complexity of all this stuff hidden away from the person wiring the test up so people with limited coding knowledge will be able to wire up the tests. Not only that if you call this in the test itself it adds a lot of bloat to it and can be hard to understand

Answer (score 2):

Typically factory methods do not take the type of object to create.  They return a type that implements some common interface and the concrete, underlying type is dependent on some argument, typically an enumerated value.  A simple example:

```
interface Whatever
{
    void SomeMethod();
}

class A : Whatever { public void Whatever() { } }

class B : Whatever { public void Whatever() { } }

enum WhateverType { TypeA, TypeB }

public void GetWhatever( WhateverType type )
{
    switch( type )
    {
        case WhateverType.TypeA:
            return new A();
            break;
        case WhateverType.TypeB:
            return new B();
            break;
        default:
            Debug.Assert( false );
    }
}
```

There you have type safety.  I'm not sure how you would implement something like that with generics as you need to supply the generic argument at compile time.